# Cannot find 127.0.0.1 or vhost with localhost apache in mac

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, localhost

I was working with localhost:81 during a long time with vhost and all was right. Right now I need to work over the 80 port and i change the http.conf and http-vhost for used the 80 port but right now into the browser localhost works ok, 127.0.0.1 and the vhost not find the server.

my configurations are:
* My local machine is lion osx
* mamp
* HTTP.conf:

```
 ServerName localhost:80
```

* http-vhost
     NameVirtualHost localhost

```
 <VirtualHost localhost>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/chalien/projects/ownProjects/PHP"
   ServerName example.dev
 </VirtualHost>
```

* /private/etc/hosts

```
 127.0.0.1  localhost
 255.255.255.255    broadcasthost
 ::1             localhost
 fe80::1%lo0    localhost
 127.0.0.1      example.dev
```

* /private/etc/services

```
  http             80/udp     www www-http # World Wide Web HTTP
  http             80/tcp     www www-http # World Wide Web HTTP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of virtual hosts is that they're used when multiple names point to the same address. So it won't be used when someone connects to the address directly. You need to add:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, in /etc/hosts you shouldn't have multiple lines with the same IP, you should combine them:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost example.dev
```

Comment: i did it and works in part. right no with the vhost in the same line in hosts file my vhost show the serverroot but not the defined into the virtualhost tag